# How to uninstall a package of which two versions are installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, uninstall

I currently have a package (opencv) installed twice on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I only realized this was the case when a Python script ran with Spyder gave me this error:

```
OSError: libopencv_highgui.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My `usr/local/lib` folder now looks like this:

```
libopencv_aruco.so                 libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3
libopencv_aruco.so.3.3             libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3.1
libopencv_aruco.so.3.3.1           libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4
libopencv_aruco.so.3.4             libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.0
libopencv_aruco.so.3.4.1           libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.1
[...]
```

The packages were initially installed following OpenCV's official [installation guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html), relying on `cmake`, `make` and on `sudo make install` commands.

The only build folder on my computer is now that of version `3.4.1`. Running `sudo make uninstall` would remove it, but I actually need to remove `3.3.1` instead.

Is there a way to uninstall the earlier version?
Would it be the same as deleting all `.3.3` and `.3.3.1` files?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell Python to ignore the first installation and only use `3.4.1`?

Comment: How exactly did you install the two versions?

Comment: @check-emee, I added a couple of lines explaining how

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall `opencv-3.3.1` and then run in the build folder `sudo make uninstall`?

Comment: @check-emee, I have not. It's an option I though of, but the installation I had done followed a particular `cmake` configuration which I do not have anymore (long story short: I tried many things, and never got OpenCV to be visible by another package, and this is why I then tried a later version). So even if I cloned a new repository with an older version of OpenCV and rebuilt the program, I'd really don't know if that would work. I also don't know if uninstalling that package would break the new installation. What would happen if I just deleted all the `.3.3` files?

Comment: Yes, maybe the best option is to manually delete all the `.3.3` files. Try to find them with `mlocate` or `find` and then delete them. A suggestion: have you considered to use a Python virtual environment? I think that is the best and easiest way to deal with different versions of packages.

Comment: @check-emee, Thanks for the suggestion. I did start with Anaconda, but couldn't get the virtual environment to work with CUDA, and ended up excluding the option. Anaconda actually caused some more trouble by ending up in paths and in CMake's "searches". If you could elaborate a short answer with the commands I have to run to delete all files I'll be happy to accept it. Only a last question: is there nowhere a sort of Python linker that will end up still thinking he should find a `.3.3` version if I delete all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76227/discussion-between-check-emee-and-raggot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way is to completely delete both version `3.4` and `3.3` and reinstall the `3.4` version.

To remove them try with

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libopencv_*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/opencv_*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/opencv*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

To check if there are still some opencv components try a search with

```
sudo updatedb
locate opencv
```

If you don't have the `updatedb`/`locate` command I suggest you to install it with `sudo apt install mlocate`.

Then try to reinstall OpenCV 3.4